# How does Java's JITter impact measuring code speed?

Tags: java, c++, profiling

I'm relatively new to Java and I was curious how Java performed on a mundane task vs C++. So I compared 2 C++ string formatting methods (sprintf and ostringstream) against using Java's StringBuilder. For each executable, the first argument I pass is the number of iterations to measure, so all the code looks roughly like

```
 int numIterations = args[0]; // or argv[1] in C++

 // measure begin here, ie: 
 int begin = System.nanoTime();
 // loop to measure
 for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; ++i)
 {
      // formatting code
 }
 // measure end here, ie
 int end = System.nanoTime();
```

This lines up with how I've seen other people profile Java code. I noticed that for small number of iterations (say 1000), Java does very poorly. For larger number of iterations, (say 1,000,000) Java does relatively well:

With 1000 iterations

```
$ ./spf.out 1000
C++  took: 1412618 ns
$ ./oss.out 1000
C++  took: 1816222 ns
$ java StringBuilderTest 1000
Java took: 25787951 ns
```

With 1000000 iterations

```
$ ./spf.out 1000000
C++  took: 1658699148 ns
$ ./oss.out 1000000
C++  took: 2053606449 ns
$java StringBuilderTest 1000000
Java took:  595965442 ns
```

I'm suspicious of the method of using begin/end timers to profile java code as I'm not sure exactly how the JITer works. Is this a vaild method of measuring Java code? Does Java have more "warming up" to do when running the code with a JIT'er? What is the canonical way of profiling Java code. Is there a way to warm up the JITer before measuring performance? Or is it just understood that for small N JITing is going to be part of the performance numbers measured?

Comment: For small N, performance numbers are mostly meaningless anyway.

Comment: @MichaelMyers yeah it seems that the specific definition of "small" may be different when comparing C++ vs Java performance. Notice how above the C++ performance for each value of n is fairly proportional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a vaild method of measuring Java code?

For the code shown yes.  Java is much smarter than C++ at eliminating code which doesn't do anything. 9 out of 10 benchmarks where Java is significantly faster, this is the case.

> Does Java have more "warming up" to do when running the code with a JIT'er?

Yes, the warm up goes through stages.  Make sure you run the test for 2-10 seconds and it should have been warm enough.  You might ignore the first 10K - 20K runs.

> What is the canonical way of profiling Java code. Is there a way to warm up the JITer before measuring performance?

There is many ways.  This is one of the simplest.

```
 long begin = 0;
 // loop to measure
 for (int i = -11000; i < numIterations; ++i)
    if (i == 0) begin = System.nanoTime();
```

> Or is it just understood that for small N JITing is going to be part of the performance numbers measured?

It depends on how realistic you want to make your test.  If in production the code will not be called 10,000 times and it doesn't warm up completely, that is what you should measure.

Comment: can code get un-warmed? Say over a year its called 10000 times, but very sporadically, could the code be un-JIT'd?

Comment: The counters can decay over time.  If you take a week to call 10,000 times it may not be compiled.  Once compiled, code can be de-optimised when the assumptions make in the compilation turn out to be invalid.  This usually results in the code being recompiled (with different assumptions)

Answer (score 0):

1000 iterations to warm up the VM; can be a bit low, I use 100 000, but warm up before starting measure.
For output of benchmark, it is better readbale if you add "time per call", not only total time.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog article](http://stuq.nl/weblog/2009-01-28/why-many-java-performance-tests-are-wrong) goes a long way to validate what I'm seeing with the hotspot VM.

To summarize, yes the HotSpot VM will warm up over a stretch of time. A lot of newbies like myself post a lot of erroneous performance tests because they are measuring VM warmup time.

To quote from the article:

> Do not draw conclusions from the performance statistics during the warm up time!
>
> - Execute your test, measure the throughput until it stabilizes. The statistics you get during the warm up time should be discarded.
> - Make sure you know how long the warm up time is for your test scenario. We use a warm up time of 10-15 minutes, which is enough for our needs. But test this yourself! It takes time for the JVM to detect the hot spots and compile the running code.

Comment: 10 to 15 minutes?!  Everything I've read says "up to 15 _seconds_"!

Comment: 10 to 15 minutes is needed if you have low latency but low throughput tests e.g. waiting on network IO.  Otherwise I would say 2-10 seconds for a CPU bound test.